# two dimension logical matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, logic

I have 'M' users that have two different characteristics of N1 and N2 possible values for each case. I.E: A is a Mx1 vector that especifies the sex {'F','M'} (N1 = 2) of each user and B is a Mx1 vector that especifies the continent where the user lives {'ASIA','AFRICA','AMERICA',etc.} (N2 = 6).
I want to create a N1xN2 (2*6) matrix that gives me the number of users for each combination of sex and continent without using a for loop.
I've tried this code:

`bsxfun(@eq,A,unique(A)')'*bsxfun(@eq,B,unique(B)')`

But it is not what i need.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I do not need the cartesian product of the values, I need a matrix counting the elements for each combination.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. Eric, you can do the following [~,~,ia] = unique(A);[~,~,ib] = unique(B);M = accumarray([ia, ib]); Not tried but should work

Comment: `M = accumarray([ia, ib])` throws he following error: "Error using accumarray Not enough input arguments." I've changed to `M = accumarray(ia, ib)` , but it returns a vector with the count for one characteristic only.

Comment: Sorry, thought the snd argument was optional. Try 'accumarray([ia,ib], 1)'

Comment: @rayryeng: Why do you think it's a duplicate ?

Comment: @G.J Upon seeing the edits, this is not a duplicate.  I'll reopen.  Please go ahead and answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need `accumarray` here :

```
[~,~,ia] = unique(A);
[~,~,ib] = unique(B);
M = accumarray([ia, ib], 1);
```